# How to convert the following js style map to clojurescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clojurescript, reagent, hiccup

I want to write this js style map in cljs:

```
const pathLength = useSpring(yRange, { stiffness: 400, damping: 90 })

<div style={{
                        pathLength,
                        rotate: 90,
                        translateX: 5,
                        translateY: 5,
                        scaleX: -1, // Reverse direction of line animation
                    }}></div>
```

I have the following:

```
[:div {:style  {path-length
               :rotate 90 :translateX 5
               :translateY 5
               :scaleX -1}}]
```

But the error I get is:

```
Map literals must contain an even number of forms.
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`{ pathLength }` in JS is short for `{ pathLength: pathLength }`.

In CLJS you just write `{:pathLength path-length}`.